# The 'Black' formatter - Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-black

I just started using the '[Black](https://pypi.org/project/black/)' formatter module with Visual Studio Code. Everything was going well till I just noticed that it uses double quotes over single quotes which I already was using in my code... And it overrode that...

So, is there an Black argument that I could add to Visual Studio Code which solves this problem?

Comment: Is that not covered in the relevant documentation?

Comment: No, I didn't find it there

Comment: Also see black issues [188](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/118#issuecomment-393298377) and [594](https://github.com/psf/black/issues/594#issuecomment-445477249).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use the `--skip-string-normalization` option at the command line, or in your Visual Studio Code options.

See *[The *Black* code style, Strings](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#strings)*.

For example:

```json
{
    ...
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--skip-string-normalization",
        "--line-length",
        "100"
    ]
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I don't know how it works for you all of that:

```
 {
    ...
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "--skip-string-normalization"
    ]
    ...
}
```

or

```
{
    ...

    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "-S"
    ],
    ...
}
```

I've tried everything and THE ONLY works for me is:

```
"black-formatter.args": ["-S"]
```

And VSCode for some reason installed via `pip install -U black` , don't know it is crucial or not.

Comment: In case of former, VS code says *This setting cannot be applied because it is not registered as language override setting.*

Comment: The first two sentences are close to incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73932754/edit) them, please?

Comment: OK, the OP has probably [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*

Answer (score 2):

`--skip-string-normalization` or `-S` for short

```
{
    ...

    "python.formatting.blackArgs": [
        "-S"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings, search for black and add argument `-S`.

[image]